# Late 70s Early 80s Children's SF Book Series

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Basic premise was a space-crew who were in some sort of rescue role. The books in the series featured a space-ship which was illustrated as very similar to the "Discovery" from "2001", but was based from a 10,000 person wheel-shaped space colony. The crew wore track-suit style outfits (70s futuristic trope) and they had an alien that was a pink blob which communicated via a small computer attached to it, which printed out messages.

One adventure has the crew encountering a ship full of the pink blob aliens.

In another they have to rescue a colony on Venus by dropping the alien into a jammed landing dome.

In another the ship goes out of control and they encounter a long-lost space-colony where the inhabitants have grown into giants.

My local library only ever seemed to have a few books from the whole series. Some of the titles on the cover end-notes sounded quite good.

Comment: Surely not the Sector General series by James White? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector_General

Comment: No such luck. They were short, large print books and illustrated.

Comment: I recall some books that fit closely with your description from the early 80s. There was definitely a very "Discovery One" like space ship. It may have even been on the cover of the first book. I recall that the books were short, squarish and contained illustrations in monochromatic colours. One story was about them traveling from Earth to Alpha Centauri and/or Planet X (or something similar) . One of the later books had the crew exploring a dangerous cave system on Planet X. Like you, I never had the whole series.

Answer (score 6):

This is a series called Galaxy 1 by, among others, Harriette Sheffer Abels, published by Crestwood House. It follows the adventures of Emergency Spaceship EM88. The pink blob with the computer is named Amorf. [Here's a link to the Google books entries](https://books.google.ca/books?id=DBiLckdZr3gC&dq=inauthor%3A%22Harriette%20Sheffer%20Abels%22).