# Looking for a children's book series set in space

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

As a child in the late 70's early 80's, my elementary school library had a series of books set in the far future featuring a group of space-faring tweens that each possessed a super-human sense or ability (similar to Mentats, Bene Gesserit) that was honed through extensive training. I can't recall the details of the stories but I know I was fascinated with them and want to share them with my children if I can find them. The books were each approximately 50-75 pages long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this question (which had better details than I did):

[Late 70s Early 80s Children's SF Book Series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/late-70s-early-80s-childrens-sf-book-series)

I can confidently say that this is the Galaxy 1 series by Harriette Sheffer Abels.