Children's sci fi books from UK primary schools in the 1980s?
Trying to find out the name of a series of UK children's sci fi books. Was at primary school from 1987-1994 and remember reading these books in the first two years.
There were several stories in the series and they were a bit like Star Trek. An established crew roving the Universe in each book and contending with various problems and enemies. The books were illustrated and seem to recall the captain having a beard and short spiky hair. In one book, I recall they diverted a river or burst a dam to wash away intergalactic gun runners (can remember a crate marked with a word like STUT washing away down a river). Another book saw the crew battling ant-human hybrids who were white and wore red uniforms and helmets.

Welcome to the SciFi & Fantasy Stack Exchange John. By "first two years" do you mean books aimed at quite young readers in the age 5-7 bracket, so mostly pictures with some words? Have a look at the lists of children's SciFi by decade on Good Reads. Here's the 1980's, with links to other decades at the top of the page.

Same book? No answer though; https://www.reddit.com/r/sciencefiction/comments/1alg0ke/late_70s_uk_junior_school_sf_reading_books/ - "Wondering if anyone here was in Junior school in the late 70s in the UK and came across a serial that spanned three sets of books (roughly 6 to 8 in each series) about a group of astronauts who travelled to the moon (first series), then travelled to Mars (second series) and then spent years travelling to a planet around Alpha Centuri (third series) where the planet's crust was fragile, and was inhabited by giant ants (if I recall)."

Possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183960/looking-for-an-old-sci-fi-book-series - The Galaxy 1 books series matches your description kinda
