# Children's sci-fi series from 70's/80's with a pink blob as a pet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel

I remember a connected series of science fiction children's books at my library from when I was a kid. This was 1983-1986, and the books might have been a few years old. These were not long books - maybe 25-35 pages each. Hardcover, and several illustrations per book. I remember the title font being that very traditional "computer font" from the early 80's.

The stories concerned the multi-ethnic crew of a space station dealing with various sci-fi tropes, such as plague in space, loss of life-support, etc. I remember it as being kind of a cross between Star Trek and Space 1999. The tone was serious, not cartoony. I remember the space plague book because they thought the plague was smallpox, but then solved it by using an old library book to identify the symptoms as chicken pox. I remember them carrying the library book out of the archive in a special container so it wouldn't crumble to dust.

One other standout detail that might jog someone's memory: one of the crew members had a pet. It was a semi-intelligent pink blob, about the size of a small dog, that could change its shape. It had a small box attached to itself that it could use to communicate via ticker tape. In one story the blob stretched itself out into a rope to climb through a pipe to rescue someone or perform some vital task.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154738/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Also mentioned at http://w1.loganberrybooks.com/stumpthebookseller/?p=3925, but no answers as of yet.

Comment: Also https://www.librarything.com/topic/212397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah-ha! Found it in another post on this forum:

[Late 70s Early 80s Children's SF Book Series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/late-70s-early-80s-childrens-sf-book-series)

Series was called "Galaxy 1", by various authors. I tried a more thorough search looking for the "pink blob" and "little computer" and (seriously) "tracksuits" :-)     . . . because the crew all wore them per 70's space drama cliche.

Thank to everyone who offered suggestions. I just found someone on eBay selling a set of these for a buck a piece (in hardcover). It will be a nice nostalgia trip.

Answer (score 0):

[Barbapapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbapapa) or a [Shmoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmoo).... but I think it's Barbapapa you're looking for.

[image: Barbapapa family]

> The main characters in the books are the Barbapapa family, who are most notable for their ability to shapeshift at will. In their native form, Barbapapas are blob-shaped, with a distinct head and arms, but no legs. Male Barbapapas have rounder bottoms, whereas female Barbapapas have a more slender form. Each Barbapapa can adopt any form they choose, but they remain easily identifiable by always retaining their faces and their distinctive colour.

Comment: This thing? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5OVl-iznSM

Comment: This thing? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1ViX0Gx3I0

Comment: Barbapapa only had one book, and no space stations. And I don't believe the Shmoos made it to space either.

Comment: That said, more details added for further reference.

Comment: Good suggestions, but neither fits. Barbapapa had several books, including one where they DID go to space in an "ark" when Earth became polluted. The books I'm looking for were more serious, less cartoony than Barbapapa/Schmoo. More like Star Trek TOS, just less violent, simpler storylines. The blob didn't have a face, personality, and was not the focus of the story. One of the crew had the blob as a pet, and occasionally used it to solve problems. e.g., once there was a malfunction on the station and the little pink blob extruded into a long worm to get into a narrow tunnel for repairs.